# How do you enable user threads in JBoss 7 AS?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Our web application which uses the ZK framework is currently running on OC4J and we have to enable user threads via the switch -userThreads.

We are looking into changing application servers to JBoss. I have managed to set up a datasource and deploy the application, but the app is having the same issue as OC4J if we didnt enable user threads.

This app works fine with Tomcat and GlassFish - and OC4J once the user threads is enabled.

So how do I enable user threads in JBoss?

Thanks!
Steve